# Grails Ant Mail Line break

Tags: java, grails, ant

I'm sure there is a very easy answer to this but how do I include a line break within the grails ant mail.  I am using the format below, and i've tried closing the quotes and using /n, HTML break tags, nothing seems to work.

```
ant.mail(mailhost:'x', mailport:'x', subject:'Test'){
                    from(address:"x")
                    replyto(address:"x")
                    to(address:"x")
                    message("Test")
```

Comment: Thanks for the code box edit, forgot to use the tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may forget to set the option to allow html tag:

```
message(mimetype:"text/html", "Your content")
```

Comment: This should work, however the body of my email is not displaying anything anymore, i've tried a combination of using <html></html> tags and such but its still sending blank e-mails, thanks for the tip.

Comment: @user618194: are you using Gmail or similar email service? If before you add that, you are able to send plain text email, then there's a chance that your html email is hidden by the email service. Try to notice if the GMail (or your email service) notice you about hiding html content, and use fire bug to check if the email is actually blank.

Comment: I'm using a local smtp server to send mail, I will see if my email client is hiding HTML based emails.  Thanks.